# How to get top (as in locale) attribute of a DIV element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a group DIV tags in an HTML page whose location is controlled via several parent/grandparent DIVs.  Those parent and grandparent's location is controlled via CSS classes.  I need to retrieve the top attribute of the given DIV.  Where is it in the DOM or how would I calculate it using Javascript?

---

Clarification:  I need the coordinate value of the top of the DIV object in absolute terms (relative to the window).

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610188/detecting-the-position-of-a-div

Comment: Yep... It is a duplicate.  I voted to close also.  I didn't just delete it since someone else might not find the other question through searching (aka the same problem I had).

Answer (score 1):

Since [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) and [offsetLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft) give you relative position values, you can get the absolute values by traversing up the tree of [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/OffsetParent)s, aggregating the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` values of each parent element:

```
function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curleft,curtop];
  }
}
```

More detailed information: [JavaScript Find position](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

Comment: I found this too.  It is almost what I need.  Is there any way to take into account scrolling?  Not just window scrolling (window.scrollY) but also DIVs with scroll:auto attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the top and left:

```
myDiv.offsetY
myDiv.offsetX
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Did you mean `offsetLeft`/`offsetRight`?

Comment: Both offsetY and offsetX are undefined.

Comment: @crescentfresh... offsetLeft is a relative value, not absolute (which I need) and offsetRight is undefined.