# How do i retrieve a div`s top value in pixels if it is set in percentage in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this `div`, which needs to be relative and the top in %:

```
#adiv {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Now i want to find the value of `top:50%` in pixels.  If I do this:

```
alert("TopHeightInPixels:"+(parseInt($("div#adiv").css("top"))));
```

Firefox outputs the actual pixels (`100px`), while Safari outputs just `50`. I know why Safari does that (with my code it just stripes the `%` of my `50%`, I guess), but how do I do it right?And if I do this using jQuery:

```
alert("TopHeightInPixels:"+(parseInt($("div#adiv").offset().top)));
```

or

```
alert("TopHeightInPixels:"+(parseInt($("div#adiv").position().top)));
```

I get a value of 0. So how do I do it the right way? Thanks in advance! [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/QcHzA/24/) the fiddle.

Comment: Can you post your result of `console.log("TopHeightInPixels:"+$("div#adiv").offset())` and `console.log("TopHeightInPixels:"+$("div#adiv").length)`?

Comment: in FF I get: TopHeightInPixels:[object Object] and TopHeightInPixels:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answers to this question: [Detecting the position of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610188/detecting-the-position-of-a-div)

The top of a div is its y coordinate usually. Unsure if the box model allows offsetting of the origin point of a div but I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Michael, thx for the quick answer, but the problem is, that offset doesnt seem to work neither as i wrote above... :-(

Comment: @suri in the fiddle you supplied the top offset is 0... check out this fiddle with a slight css mod http://jsfiddle.net/vfLKj/

Comment: Yeah, but did you try the other answer in that link that mentions the Google code?

Comment: Also sorry, I didn't realise you were using jQuery already. Must have skipped past that.

Answer (score 1):

The `top` attribute sets your position relative to its parent, but the parent needs to have a height in order for this to work using percentages.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju7WG/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#adiv').offset().top
```